# Is Descent into Avernus the only Adventurers League Season 9 module?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

I can only find one module, *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*, for a season 9 module for AL. Are there any other season 9 modules?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 9):

*Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* is not a module as DDAL defines them, it is a "hardcover adventure". The individual modules are available on the [DM's Guild](https://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=45470_45832_0_0_0_0_0_0).

You'll want to consult the [DDAL Player's & DM's Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack), particularly the Player's and DM's guides with in it to see what the distinction between hardcover adventures and modules is.

That bundle also includes the content catalog, a listing of the available modules and hardcover adventures.